# Web pages on a Screensaver

Tags: web, screensaver

I'm trying to make my office a bit more professional and I need the employees to check constantly some web pages. Is there a way to have two or three web pages rotating on a screensaver? And also need them to be updated quite often...Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing OS related information. Also have you tried searching by yourself ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6680625/3363219

Comment: A screensaver is usually displayed when the computer is not being used... surely, your staff letting their computers go to screensaver when they're at their computer shows a lack of productivity? Additionally, if your staff *are* being productive and are at their desk and not looking at their computer (to allow the screensaver to come on) then they'd not be looking at your screensaver... any solution you find will have minimal impact on productivity. A better solution would be to have, say, some additional screens or a large monitor(s) in the office to permanently show your desired webpages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution for Mac OS X, we made a product that is exactly what you are looking for: [Screensaver Ninja](https://Screensaver.Ninja).

If you are looking for a solution for Windows, we are in the process of building it: [Screensaver Ninja for Windows](https://Screensaver.Ninja/for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can look up some free tools for that purpose, such as:
http://www.web-screen-saver.com/download.html
, depends on your OS and hardware.

There are some very good priced tools for that too:
http://www.finalhit.com/downloads/ultra-screen-saver-maker/

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks ;). I've tried to input some more but being new currently prevents me from tagging users, share more than certain amounts of contents etc. I'd like to ask Richard Hall what OS does he have and for some more details, but I cannot comment on his post - still.

Comment: The main thing isn't more recommendations, but more information about the ones you do recommend.  For example, are you a satisfied user or did you just stumbled across them on Google?  Do they do everything described in the question?  What makes these programs particularly good as a solution (vs. any random Google hits)?  If you can: what's the gist of the procedure to set up what's asked in the question?  If screenshots would be helpful, post links to them at a sharing site, like imgur.com, and someone will embed them for you.